# phpUnit throws "call to a member function get() on a non-object while getting Entity Manager

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am new to phpUnit testing. I have been trying to test models in a program. Models extend to BasicModel where Doctrine EntityManager is set. Each time I test a method which calls this part in BasicModel I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /pathTo/Model/BasicModel.php on line 53
```

On line 53 there is

```
$this->setEntityManager($this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'));
```

The question is: how do I get around this? I have tried to mock the EntityManager and BasicModel but the result is always the same. My test looks like this:

```
class MyModelTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   public function setUp()
   {
     $this->sm = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
     $this->em = $this->sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
     $this->model = new MyModel($this->em);

     $bm = $this->getMock('pathTo\Model\BasicModel');
     $bm->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getEntityManager')
        ->will($this->returnValue($this->em));

    parent::setUp();
}

public function testMyFunction()
{
    $result = $this->model->myFunction();

    $this->assertInstanceOf('myEntity', $result);
}
```

The method under testing looks like this:

```
class MyModel extends BasicModel {

public function myFunction()
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $something = $em->getRepository('path\to\someEntity')->someMethod();

    return $something;
}
}
```

(Some of) BasicModel's methods looks like this:

```
class BasicModel implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {
protected function getEntityManager() {
    if (null === $this->entityManager) {
        $this->setEntityManager($this->getServiceLocator()
              ->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'));

    }
    return $this->entityManager;
}

public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl) {
    $this->serviceLocator = $sl;
    return $this;
}

public function getServiceLocator() {
    return $this->serviceLocator;
}
}
```

UPDATE:
I tried the following to MyModelTest setUp (as Tim Fountain suggested):

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->sm = Bootstrap::getServiceManager();    
    $this->model = new MyModel();
    $this->model->setServiceLocator($this->sm);
    parent::setUp();
}
```

but it results in:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 
'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

So what should I try next? :)

Comment: How does the service locator get into the model? Its absence is what's causing the error.

Comment: There's also this function in the BasicModel: setServiceLocator, which I added to my previous post. ServiceLocatorInterface is Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface.

Comment: Okay, but you've not answered my question - how does the service locator get into the model? It seems like you're missing a `$this->model->setServiceLocator($this->sm);` in your `setUp()` method.

Comment: Which model do you mean: BasicModel, MyModelTest or the model under testing?

Comment: I mean `MyModel` - the one you are testing.

Comment: MyModel extends to BasicModel, so BasicModel is the source (to my knowledge). This is my friend's program I'm testing.

Answer (score 0):

In your `setUp`-Method you assign the Service-Manager to the Variable `$this->sm`. But when accessing the locator via `getServiceLocator`, you try to use `$this->serviceLocator`.
Try to fix that first and use the correct variable name, either in `setUp` or in the Getter-Method.

Also, you dont really return a Service Locator. That´s more just the Name of the Pattern/Interface which the Service Manager implements. But thats not part of the problem, just a hint;)